# React Native - My native function is not recognized

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to do a bridge to return a promise. But the react-native is not recognizing my native function. I did everything that has in the documentation and everything that i saw in the community but nothing worked.

Down below is the function that i want to return to JavaScript.

```
 @objc  
func login( resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {

NSLog("Using \(String(describing: profile.version))")
let customAttributes : [String : Array<String>] = [THMCustomAttributes:
  ["ola"]]
profile.doProfileRequest(options: customAttributes, andCallbackBlock:
  {(result: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void in
    let results:NSDictionary! = result! as NSDictionary
    let status:THMStatusCode  =
      THMStatusCode(rawValue:(results.value(forKey: THMProfileStatus) as!
        NSNumber).intValue)!
    self.sessionID = results.value(forKey: THMSessionID) as! String
    if(status == .ok)
    {
      resolve(self.sessionID)
    }
    NSLog("Profile completed with: %@ and session ID: \(self.sessionID)",
      status == .ok                  ? "OK"                   :
        status == .networkTimeoutError ? "Timed out"            :
        status == .connectionError ? "Connection Error"     :
        status == .hostNotFoundError ? "Host Not Found Error" :
        status == .internalError  ? "Internal Error"       :
        status == .interruptedError  ? "Interrupted Error"    :
      "Other" )
    Fingerprint.usefulSessionID = self.sessionID
})
```

}
-- Here is the code used for the function exportation:

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Fingerprint, NSObject)
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(
                  login
                  resolve: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject
                  )
@end
```

-- Down below is the code of the Header:

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
#import <TrustDefender/TrustDefender.h>
```

-- Javascript code

```
NativeModules.Fingerprint.login()
          .then(token => {
            // do something useful...
          })
          .catch(error => {
            throw error
          })
```

-- Error shown in the device

[image: Error that appears in the Javascript]

Comment: By any chance did you manage to fix this issue? (seems like you were trying to obtain a fingerprint for Cybersource API calls)